# SwiftUI: Assert that sheet is visible

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I have a view in which a sheet gets visible at some point.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Test")
        Text("Test")
    }.sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
        MySheet(isPresented: $isPresented)
    })
}
```

The sheet looks like this:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { metrics in
        VStack (spacing:0) {
            ZStack {
                Color(UIColor.lightGray)
                Text("header")
            }.frame(width: metrics.size.width, height: metrics.size.height * 0.15)
            ZStack {
                Color(UIColor.darkGray)
                Text("text")
            }.frame(width: metrics.size.width, height: metrics.size.height * 0.85)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to test that the sheet is visible with

```
XCTAssertTrue(app.textFields["header"].exists)
```

But that does not work.
How can I test if the sheet is visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Text` you need to use `staticTexts` container (tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1). *Assuming of course that your test correctly wait till sheet is opened.*

```
XCTAssertTrue(app.staticTexts["header"].exists)
```